# How can I refactor a function to be inline?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm refactoring functions trying to do  more of a in-line aproach.

```
        private int GetRandomNumberHigherThanHalf()
        {
            double randomNumber= Random.NextDouble();

            if (randomNumber < 0.5)
                throw new Exception("randomNumber is lower than 0.5");

            return randomNumber;
        }
```

Any ideas about how can I refactor the function above to one line? It has to trhow an Exception and return the number generated.

Comment: Not sure why you want to throw potentially half of the times. 

    `return randomNumber > 0.5 ?  randomNumber : 1 - randomNumber`

Comment: I've possibly over-simplified the code to be more "dummy", it is actually a database connection beign stablished

Comment: Then I don't think it is worth it. Readability > concision .

Comment: This question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: @Mast Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take your request at face value. Add an extension method:

```
public static class UselessExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIf<T>(this T input, Func<T, bool> predicate, string message)
        => predicate(input) ? throw new Exception(message) : input;
}
```

Then use that in your method:

```
// One liner
private double GetRandomNumberHigherThanHalf()
    => Random.NextDouble().ThrowIf(r => r < 0.5, "randomNumber is lower than 0.5");
```

Your original code doesn't compile, there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `int`.

---

Would you want to do this? No. Lines of code is a bad metric. You want your code to be as readable as possible. Not to be as short as possible. In this case, it stays readable because the extension method is well-named. You want to aim for your code being as concise as possible without affecting how easy it is to read.

Comment: It realy does not compile, my bad. But, why wouldn't I try to make it a one liner? I've got a quite few functions like that eventually increases the class file size.

Answer (score -1):

You are a new contributor and we try to be nice, but one can only be so nice when the code AND the most of your reasoning is so poor.

THIS SOUNDS LIKE HOMEWORK with all the restrictions you are giving.

You seem to be obsessed with making this a one-liner.  Such obsessions will weigh you down and lead to poor code.  Use one-liners where they make the best sense in a short, simple call.

You return an int but use a double internally.  If you cast the double to an int, your method will always (A) return 0 or (B) throw an exception.

There is the Principle of Least Astonishment and your code violates in 2 ways.  If a caller wants to GetRandomNumberHigherThanHalf, then it would astonish them to throw an exception.  They would expect the method would correctly keep trying until it finds the right value to return.  And the 2nd violation is that your method could return 0.5, which is NOT HIGHER than Half.

Make up your mind if you really want a Double or an int.  If you want an int, you may want it to fall within a range, so you could use this [Next overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

If you take time to read the [Random constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) comments, look at the bottom at this text:

> Another option is to instantiate a single Random object that you use
> to generate all the random numbers in your application. This yields
> slightly better performance, since instantiating a random number
> generator is fairly expensive.

With your method, if you quickly call it repeatedly, then it will not return a different random number, but rather the same number.  If you instantiated a Random instance once for your class, then you would not have this problem.

Again, if you clearly think out what you want ... do you want a Double > 0.5 but less than 1.0, or do you want a Double scaled between 2 values, or do you want an integer falling between 2 values, then pick the right Random method.  And I would not throw if the value is less than 0.5; rather I would simply add 0.5 to the returned value.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for taking the time to write an response.